Is this blade too pitted?
Six months ago I started woodworking, then two weeks ago, somewhat impulsively, I decided to restore a fairly rusted  Stanley no 5 type 14 I found on eBay. The blade has quite a bit of pitting, which worries me. I took these pictures after doing some sanding on the primary bevel at 25° with 120 sandpaper, and of the back, also with 120 sandpaper, on a flat surface.
Is this blade going to work or is it beyond hope?
Front of blade

Back of blade


Looks good to me!

Although the blade is pitted, the only part that really matters is the very edge of the blade (say the last 1/16 inch) so it may be possible to get more life out of it. However, from the pictures, it looks like you have some work to do to get it into shape to work well. You will have to work on both the front and back of the blade.

I would recommend that the blade bevel side be ground to 25 degrees angle with a squared edge.  You can do this with a grinder, a rough grit stone, or sandpaper on a flat marble slab (approx. 220 +/- grit, I have used a marble floor tile as a work surface). Bear in mind that without a grinder there will be a lot of elbow grease and several hours in getting there.
The back side must also be flattened with the part near the blade perfectly flat and eventually polished smooth at the edge 1/8 +/-. You can tell if the near edge is flat because all of the scratch marks I see there will be gone and that area close to the edge will be on its way to mirror like finish.
After you have a 25 degree bevel straight across and perpendicular to the sides of the blade you will begin polishing.  I would recommend doing it in steps.  I use 600, 1200, & 2000 grit stones.  The first step is to do both sides with the 600 grit on the front until I have a flat uniform surface.  It will now shine a bit but is not mirror like.  After working on the bevel you should feel a burr across the back side of the edge. I then lay the back flat on the stones and do about 5-10 strokes to remove the burr. By this point, if the edge is unpitted, you should be able to reuse the blade. So I continue on.
With the 600 grit work done, I then do a bit more on both sides with the 1200 grit.  This step is purely cosmetic for me, but I like it to look better.
You could continue polishing with the 1200 $ 2000 and some woodworkers may, but I prefer a different approach.  The only part of the blade that does the work is the very edge that extends beyond the chip breaker, and that is where I put my initial and resharpening work. First, I use the 1200 grit on the back face but instead of having the blade flat against the stone I turn it perpendicular to the stone length and tilt it up at a slope of approx. 1/32" in 2" from flat and polish it so that only the last 1/16" of the blade is polished across the width of the blade. I then turn to the front and polish the front at an angle of 30 degrees until the front 1/16"+ is polished creating a visible secondary bevel on the main bevel. (Note, I only provide a back bevel on plane blades, chisel backs must be polished absolutely flat).
I then repeat the process above using the 2000 grit stone.
Finally, I use a leather strop to hone the edge top and bottom.

Because the last three steps are only working on a small portion of the blade, they do not take that much time. Only working such a small area also means that resharpening is much quicker too.
Of course, having a super sharp blade means very little if the plane body is not in good condition too.  There are plenty of youtube videos that talk about how to tune up the plane body as well. You can post pictures of the plane body and parts in another question to get discussion on how to restore that if you need to.
Finally, note many woodworkers have different opinions on how to sharpen a blade so there may be comments saying so. This is how I do it and it works well enough for me to shave hairs on my arm.

Very detailed instructions—thanks

An important addition for beginners is to keep the blade cool, otherwise you can ruin the heat treatment.

I forgot to mention that a blade sharpening guide is very useful. I recommend one with two wheels to help ensure that the blade is ground perpendicular to the edges.


Is this blade too pitted?

No.
Although this iron is indeed badly pitted I've restored significantly worse1, and sometimes with much less effort than I expected2.
In general
In terms of function, pits on the bevel side don't matter at all.
It is not an uncommon misconception that bad pitting on this side does render a blade unsalvageable, and a few books and numerous articles/webpages basically say this in plain English. But that's nonsense since these pits don't intersect with the edge and never will.... rendering any pitting, no matter how severe, completely irrelevant.
Initially, pitting on the bevel itself is of course an issue if a smooth continuous edge is the goal, but this is easily taken care of by regrinding which on a power grinder (even a low-speed wet grinder) takes mere minutes. If you have to remove bad pitting on the bevel entirely by hand it takes a while longer, but it's still doable as you've already discovered; for future readers it's especially efficient if one uses a very coarse diamond plate (150 or coarser).
Pits on the flat side of a plane iron (chisels too) are, conventionally, more important, but again only if they will intersect with the edge.
Specific to this iron
Since you can ignore the bevel side, we need consider the back only.
It appears you have a smattering of pits remaining near to the edge (the only portion of this surface you need think about for now). Conventionally this means you have more work to do to remove them — either by continuing to abrade this surface, or by grinding back the edge to move it behind the pits.
I generally do a combination of these things IF I'm looking to get rid of all pitting from near the edge. However, I don't always do this any longer.....
Throwing convention out the window
Now here's the bit that will blow the mind of any traditionalist, you can actually ignore pits on the flat for most bench-plane irons.
Sounds crazy3 but here's why: will the plane be the last thing to touch the wood before finish is applied? Even if the iron is fitted to a no. 3 or 4, the answer is highly, highly likely to be no because almost nobody in the west finish planes like this any more (and it actually hasn't been common practice for hundreds of years...... hence why scrapers exist in such profusion on the secondhand market).
And here, this is a no. 5..... in common usage 5s are not finishing planes (not that it would matter if they were, because scraping and/or sanding).
No. 5s, AKA jack planes, are generally jack-of-all-trades kinds of planes, or, even better, a type of roughing plane (a "roughing jack") so will NEVER be the last thing to touch the wood on any surface that matters. Ergo, any tracks left on the surface are utterly irrelevant.
So you can just hone the iron right now4 and set to work once the remainder of the restoration is completed.

1 Both in terms of depth (especially on old, tapered irons found in wooden planes) and number, on irons of all vintages including thinner modern irons. Modern should be understood to mean 'since the introduction of metallic planes' in this context, so includes irons a century old and more.
2 By ignoring all pitting that doesn't matter now, or for the foreseeable future — say a period of a few years for someone who uses the plane a lot and literal decades for someone who uses it infrequently.
3 And yes, this gets a lot of pushback (even after the explanation of why *le sigh*)
4 I would finish honing on a 1000# diamond plate then strop. Your mileage may vary, but know that you don't need to go through a long progression of grits when honing.

A trove of information — thanks
